# email alert to people in the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, email, alert

The requirement is to send an email alert with the URL(same sharepoint URL) to the newly add list item. for example, if i add an employee detail in the list(which is having columns as employee name, id and email id), an email alert should send to the newly added employee with the URL of the same sharepoint. 
Thanks and Regards
Senthil D

Answer (score 1):

**Workflow**: Create a workflow in SharePoint Designer which sends email to the user mentioned in the list field. Use `Send an Email` activity in the designer and the url of the item can be embedded in the mail body by appending the ID of the added item with list display form. Example: `/DispForm.aspx?ID=1`

**Event Handler**: Write ItemAdded event handler and send the mail to the user by using `SPUtility.SendEmail`.